# How do I save an updated version of a word document without having to create a new file name? i.e. save over an existing document?

Tags: ms-office

When emailing a Word document back and forth with multiple comments I am unable to save over an existing file. The file name is greyed out and wont allow me to save.

I have to create a new file name each time a new comment is added.

Comment: And if you just click 'Save"?

Comment: Where (in which path) are you trying to save it?

Comment: When I open the file it opens as read only. I can't save unless I select "duplicate" on the file. Then I am trying to save it into a folder under my documents. The original is already saved, but "greyed" out and so I cant save over the old file (hope that makes sense)...

Comment: I think everyone has already answered though that this is not possible - a "safety feature"... Thank you so much for your help though :)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to modify the file that's attached to the email. You can't modify the contents of an email you've received.

When you open the email, if you want to modify the Word document, save it first (to Downloads, Desktop, Documents, etc.), modify it, then mail it back.

Or continue to do what you're already doing, either is fine.

Answer (score -1):

Detach the file. Get Info to make sure it's read/write, modify and save a new copy.... attach...

In IMAP email attachments are stored on Email server, Mac, iPhone... if you could dynamically modify attachment in email then system would get unstable.